# Передача по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том ,что в метод InnerFilter переменная report_group_date 
передается по ссылке, 2 строкой в методе innerFilter запускается. Slice по словам документации должен вернуть значение, а переменная report_group_date должна остаться не изменой. Но по каким-то неведомым мне причинам все манипуляции с r влияют и на report_group_date. Как решить данную проблему?

```
function filter(from, to){
        report_group_date.reverse();
        var df = DateConvert(from);
        var dt = DateConvert(to);
        if(df.valueOf() > dt.valueOf()) {return false;}
        var f = BinarySerchOnDateInPayments(df, report_group_date);
        var t = BinarySerchOnDateInPayments(dt, report_group_date.slice(f));
        t = f+t;
        if(t == null || f == null || (t == f && f == report_group_date.length) || (t == 0 && f == 0)){ return false }
        var result = report_group_date.slice(f,t);
        report_group_date.reverse();
        result.reverse();
        InnerFilter(result);
        return result;
    }

    function InnerFilter(result)
    {
        var r = result.slice(0);
        var service_type = $('#service-type').multipleSelect('getSelects');
        var client_type = $('#client-type').multipleSelect('getSelects');
        var num_card = $('#num-card-type').multipleSelect('getSelects');
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            var trans = [];
            for(var j = 0; j < r[i].trans.length; j++)
            {
                if(filterService(service_type, r[i].trans[j][1]))
                {
                    trans.push(r[i].trans[j]);
                }
            }
            r[i].trans = trans.slice(0);
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602729/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8